# Return only one line per file with grep in Terminal

Tags: terminal, command-line

Various posts in other forums have suggested that the best way to use `grep` to return a single line per file is using `-m 1`, which is the `--max-count` option. However, when I write the following line, I get *only* one file, not one line per file:

`grep -m 1 "library" ./ -R`

Returns a single file on a single line:

```
.//results/fig/fig_functions.R:# library(plyr)
```

Whereas

`grep "library" ./ -R`

Returns many files, each with multiple lines:

```
.//results/fig/fig_functions.R:# library(plyr)
.//results/fig/fig_functions.R:# library(grid)
.//src/rmd/genevese_params.html:library(sf) 
.//src/rmd/genevese_params.html:library(raster)
[many more lines and files...]
```

I would like the command to return *all* files containing the text, but only return one line per file. Am I using `grep` incorrectly or is there another way to do this?

Comment: If you only want to see what files have a match, and you don't care what the match actually is, use the `-l` option: `grep -lR "library" .`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not working as expected because Macs use a BSD version of `grep` while the answers you're seeing are for GNU `grep` as found on Linux. They're very similar but not identical, and they handle `-m` differently. BSD `grep` treats `-m` as covering the full output, while GNU's version is per-file.

One way to get the result you describe is like this:

```
find . -type f -exec grep -H -m1 library '{}' \;
```

This uses `find` to get the path to every file in `.` (recursively, so it gets all sub-directories) an then runs `grep -m1` on each of them. The `-type f` tells `find` to only get regular files, not directories and other things. The `-H` tells `grep` to print the names of matching files, not just the matching text.

Another way would be to install GNU `grep`, using [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/).